# JavaFX - DatePicker throws unrecoverable exception when losing focus on invalid date

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I stumbled over an annoying problem while trying to extend the DatePicker control (JavaFX SDK 21.0.02).

When an invalid date was entered into the textfield and the focus is lost without pressing enter beforhand you will receive an
`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor`

This exception will not be thrown when the invalid input will be commited by pressing enter.

The DatePicker constructor installs a focus listener that is suppose to handle this situation through validation using the current converter.

```
        focusedProperty().addListener(o -> {
            if (!isFocused()) {
                commitValue();
            }
        });
```

and

```
    public final void commitValue() {
        if (!isEditable()) {
            return;
        }
        String text = getEditor().getText();
        StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = getConverter();
        if (converter != null) {
            LocalDate value = converter.fromString(text);
            setValue(value);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately the exception is raised before the fromString method is reached. It happens in the depths of the resolveDate method of the default Chronolgy of the DatePicker.

To demonstrate this behavior here is a sample application:

```
package application;
    
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.Chronology;
import java.time.chrono.Era;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalField;
import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.GERMAN);
        
        try {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
            
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            
            FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
            NewPicker datePicker = new NewPicker();
            
            datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener((v, o, n)->{
                if (!n) System.out.println("Focus lost on DatePicker");
            });
            
            datePicker.getEditor().focusedProperty().addListener((v, o, n)->{
                if (!n) System.out.println("Focus lost on DatePickers TextField");
            });
            
            
            Chronology chronology = datePicker.getChronology();
            
            datePicker.setChronology(new Chronology() {
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate resolveDate(Map<TemporalField, Long> fieldValues, ResolverStyle resolverStyle) {
                    System.out.println("Reached resolveDate with fieldValues " + fieldValues +
                        " and resolverStyle " + resolverStyle);
                    
                    ChronoLocalDate test = null;
                    
                    try {
                        test = chronology.resolveDate(fieldValues, resolverStyle);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception in resolveDate with fieldValues " + fieldValues +
                            " and resolverStyle " + resolverStyle);
                    }
                    
                    return test;
                }
                @Override public ValueRange range(ChronoField field) {
                    return chronology.range(field); }
                @Override public int prolepticYear(Era era, int yearOfEra) {
                    return chronology.prolepticYear(era, yearOfEra); }
                @Override public boolean isLeapYear(long prolepticYear) {
                    return chronology.isLeapYear(prolepticYear); }
                @Override public String getId() {
                    return chronology.getId(); }
                @Override public String getCalendarType() {
                    return chronology.getCalendarType(); }
                @Override public List<Era> eras() {
                    return chronology.eras(); }
                @Override public Era eraOf(int eraValue) {
                    return chronology.eraOf(eraValue); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate dateYearDay(int prolepticYear, int dayOfYear) {
                    return chronology.dateYearDay(prolepticYear, dayOfYear); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate dateEpochDay(long epochDay) {
                    return chronology.dateEpochDay(epochDay); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate date(int prolepticYear, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    return chronology.date(prolepticYear, month, dayOfMonth); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate date(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
                    return chronology.date(temporal);
                }
                @Override public int compareTo(Chronology other) { 
                    return chronology.compareTo(other); }
            });
            
            
            datePicker.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<LocalDate>(new LocalDateStringConverter() {
                @Override public LocalDate fromString(String value) {
                    System.out.println("Reached fromString with value " + value);
                    
                    try {
                        if (value!=null && !value.isBlank())
                            System.out.println("Parsed: " + df.parse(value));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception in fromString");
                        //datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
                        datePicker.getEditor().setText(df.format(Date.from(Instant.now())));
                        return LocalDate.now();
                        }
                    
                    return super.fromString(value);
                }
                @Override public String toString(LocalDate value) {
                    System.out.println("Reached toString");
                    return super.toString(value);
                }
            }));
            
            flowPane.getChildren().add(datePicker);
            flowPane.getChildren().add(new TextField());
            
            root.getChildren().add(flowPane);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    private class NewPicker extends DatePicker {
    }
}
```

Launch the application and enter 1.13.2024 (German date) with pressing enter.
Input then 1.13.2024 and press tab.

To be clear: in the end you will reach fromString and will be able to fix the issue but the unexpcted exception remains.

How can I prevent this behaviour with reasonable effort?

Thanks in advance for any help!

The expected behaviour is the same as when the text was commited. The sample application shows what I tried to locate the issue.

Comment: This appears to be a bug which is fixed in the upcoming version. Compare the `DatePicker` [source code for version 21](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx21/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.java#L148) to the [current development branch](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.java#L148).

Comment: If you regard this as critical, you could use the latest early-access JavaFX version (currently `22-ea+27`). Generally I do not recommend using early access versions unless you have a very compelling reason. In this case, the only issue seems to be the generation of the stack trace (the UI seems to function perfectly fine), so I would recommend just waiting until version 22 is released (March 2024) and living with the stack trace until then.

Comment: *"Unfortunately the exception is raised before the fromString method is reached."* This doesn't appear to be the case, at least not in `21.0.1`. The `fromString()` method invokes `LocalDate.from(TemporalAccessor)` which throws the exception. You should include the complete stack trace if you're seeing something different to that.

Comment: You can also fix this pretty easily in the current version by supplying a custom converter. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: replace the converter, not the text formatter.

This is a bug in the current stable release (at the time of writing, version 21.0.2.) It has been fixed in the current ea version (`22-ea+27`) which is due for release in March 2024, though I am not sure if the fix gives you exactly the behavior you are trying to implement.

Running on 21.0.2 produces the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=1},org.jamesd.examples.dialogsize.Main$1@5eea803f of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:403)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateTimeStringConverter$LdtConverter.fromString(LocalDateTimeStringConverter.java:206)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.fromString(LocalDateStringConverter.java:134)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.fromString(LocalDateStringConverter.java:45)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.commitValue(DatePicker.java:445)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.lambda$new$2(DatePicker.java:150)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node$FocusPropertyBase.notifyListeners(Node.java:8142)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node$17.notifyListeners(Node.java:8214)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.notifyFocusListeners(Node.java:8163)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$FocusOwnerProperty.invalidated(Scene.java:2253)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.setFocusOwner(Scene.java:2304)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.requestFocus(Scene.java:2201)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.requestFocusVisible(Node.java:8423)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node$1.requestFocusVisible(Node.java:625)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.requestFocusVisible(NodeHelper.java:312)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TopMostTraversalEngine.focusAndNotify(TopMostTraversalEngine.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TopMostTraversalEngine.trav(TopMostTraversalEngine.java:106)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.traverse(Scene.java:2159)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.traverse(Node.java:8437)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node$1.traverse(Node.java:526)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.traverse(NodeHelper.java:238)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.FocusTraversalInputMap.traverse(FocusTraversalInputMap.java:97)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.FocusTraversalInputMap.traverseNext(FocusTraversalInputMap.java:137)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8875)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$new$3(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:173)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ListenerHelper$EvHa.handle(ListenerHelper.java:508)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventFilterRecord.handleCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:321)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:98)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:219)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:178)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:43)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:52)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2194)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2715)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:150)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:249)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:542)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
```

You can see from the stack trace that the listener registered with the date picker's `focusedProperty` invokes `LocalDateStringConverter.fromString()` via the code you posted

```
focusedProperty().addListener(o -> {
    if (!isFocused()) {
        commitValue();
    }
});
```

and

```
    public final void commitValue() {
        if (!isEditable()) {
            return;
        }
        String text = getEditor().getText();
        StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = getConverter();
        if (converter != null) {
            LocalDate value = converter.fromString(text);
            setValue(value);
        }
    }
```

The (default) converter here throws an exception if the text is not valid. So the simplest fix is simply to replace the converter. You already have one defined (but not installed), but you need to modify it so that if an exception is thrown in parsing it returns a default value (it appears you want this to be `LocalDate.now()`). It's probably not a good idea to mix the legacy `java.text.DateFormat` with the new `java.time` API. (By default, the converter uses a `DateTimeFormatter` using the current default `Locale` and `FormatStyle.SHORT`. If you want to modify this further, parse the text with a custom `DateTimeFormatter`. Here I just rely on the default and revert if that throws an exception; I think that gives you what you are trying to do.)

```
            LocalDateStringConverter localDateStringConverter = new LocalDateStringConverter() {
                @Override
                public LocalDate fromString(String value) {
                    System.out.println("Reached fromString with value " + value);

                    try {
                       return super.fromString(value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception in fromString");
                         return LocalDate.now();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String toString(LocalDate value) {
                    System.out.println("Reached toString");
                    return super.toString(value);
                }
            };
```

Then install the converter. (As I understand it, by default the text formatter will use the converter you install, so there is no need to do that in addition.)

```
            datePicker.setConverter(localDateStringConverter);
//            datePicker.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<LocalDate>(localDateStringConverter));
```

Here is a complete version of your example code, with the fix (and also removing legacy API):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.Chronology;
import java.time.chrono.Era;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalField;
import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainFixed extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
//            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
            NewPicker datePicker = new NewPicker();

            datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener((v, o, n)->{
                if (!n) System.out.println("Focus lost on DatePicker");
            });

            datePicker.getEditor().focusedProperty().addListener((v, o, n)->{
                if (!n) System.out.println("Focus lost on DatePickers TextField");
            });


            Chronology chronology = datePicker.getChronology();

            datePicker.setChronology(new Chronology() {
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate resolveDate(Map<TemporalField, Long> fieldValues, ResolverStyle resolverStyle) {
                    System.out.println("Reached resolveDate with fieldValues " + fieldValues +
                            " and resolverStyle " + resolverStyle);

                    ChronoLocalDate test = null;

                    try {
                        test = chronology.resolveDate(fieldValues, resolverStyle);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception in resolveDate with fieldValues " + fieldValues +
                                " and resolverStyle " + resolverStyle);
                    }

                    return test;
                }
                @Override public ValueRange range(ChronoField field) {
                    return chronology.range(field); }
                @Override public int prolepticYear(Era era, int yearOfEra) {
                    return chronology.prolepticYear(era, yearOfEra); }
                @Override public boolean isLeapYear(long prolepticYear) {
                    return chronology.isLeapYear(prolepticYear); }
                @Override public String getId() {
                    return chronology.getId(); }
                @Override public String getCalendarType() {
                    return chronology.getCalendarType(); }
                @Override public List<Era> eras() {
                    return chronology.eras(); }
                @Override public Era eraOf(int eraValue) {
                    return chronology.eraOf(eraValue); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate dateYearDay(int prolepticYear, int dayOfYear) {
                    return chronology.dateYearDay(prolepticYear, dayOfYear); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate dateEpochDay(long epochDay) {
                    return chronology.dateEpochDay(epochDay); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate date(int prolepticYear, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    return chronology.date(prolepticYear, month, dayOfMonth); }
                @Override public ChronoLocalDate date(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
                    return chronology.date(temporal);
                }
                @Override public int compareTo(Chronology other) {
                    return chronology.compareTo(other); }
            });


            LocalDateStringConverter localDateStringConverter = new LocalDateStringConverter() {
                @Override
                public LocalDate fromString(String value) {
                    System.out.println("Reached fromString with value " + value);

                    try {
                       return super.fromString(value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception in fromString");
                         return LocalDate.now();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String toString(LocalDate value) {
                    System.out.println("Reached toString");
                    return super.toString(value);
                }
            };

            datePicker.setConverter(localDateStringConverter);
//            datePicker.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<LocalDate>(localDateStringConverter));

            flowPane.getChildren().add(datePicker);
            flowPane.getChildren().add(new TextField());

            root.getChildren().add(flowPane);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class NewPicker extends DatePicker {
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned, this is a bug in versions 21 and earlier. The source code for 21.0.2, which can be retrieved [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx21/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.java#L148) has

```
        focusedProperty().addListener(o -> {
            if (!isFocused()) {
                commitValue();
            }
        });
```

The source code for the [current development version (retrieved on February 6th 2024)](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.java#L148) has

```
        focusedProperty().addListener(o -> {
            if (!isFocused()) {
                try {
                    commitValue();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
```

which fixes the problem out of the box. So you can use `22-ea+27` (or later), though I think supplying the converter is actually what you seem to need anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

It makes sense to set the converter also to the control itself instead of only the underlying TextField.

I was under the assumption that it would make no difference because the converter in the TextField was seemingly activated as expected.

Will use your suggestion with great appreciation.